# Retrieving null and non null string value from JSON String

Tags: java, json, string, null

I have a JSON String that I am parsing, and I want to retrieve the value of the field "pr_num". I am getting this error:

```
JSONObject["pr_num"] is not a JSONArray.
```

My code is below:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);

JSONArray data = obj.getJSONArray("pr_num");
JSONObject obj1= data.getJSONObject(0);
System.out.println("JSON CONTENTS ARE"+obj1.getString("pr_num"));
```

I want to get values for `pr_num` field which are `690052` and `null`.

jsonString is mention below

```
[{
    "executed_by": "vishnuc",
    "testplan_id": 17372,
    "pr_num": "690052"
},
{
    "executed_by": "kkavitha",
    "testplan_id": 17372,
    "pr_num": null

}]
```

Comment: What don't you understand about `JSONObject["pr_num"] is not a JSONArray`?

Comment: So how can i retrieve multiple instances of pr_num from this string?

Comment: `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);` is incompatible with the given input.

Comment: json is String which is equal to [{
    "executed_by": "vishnuc",
    "testplan_id": 17372,
    "pr_num": "690052",
},
{
    "executed_by": "kkavitha",
    "testplan_id": 17372,
    "pr_num": null,

}]    ---- The same one i have already posted above.

Comment: Also, I checked my jsonString  with  http://jsonlint.com/ and it is valid string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your jsonString is a json formatted array
So first you have to get it to a json array (not to an json object)

```
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

Now you can iterate through the obj array

```
for(int i=0;i<obj.length();i++){
 System.out.println("content one: " + obj.getJSONObject(i).getString("pr_num"));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to retrieve value. one issue is if the value of field pr_num is null i am getting this error, JSONObject["pr_num"] not a string. if i put it under try, catch block it is working fine. Any other graceful way for handling null values for pr_num field?

Comment: You are welcome. Check it like the following link,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226288/json-jsonobject-optstring-returns-string-null