# optstring not converting to string [aws json object]

Tags: java, json, string, amazon-web-services

I am using `com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject`

In the documentation it says

> public String optString(String key)
>
> Get an optional string associated with a key. It returns an empty string if there is no such key. If the value is not a string and is not null, then it is coverted to a string.
>
> Parameters:
>       key - A key string.
>   Returns:
>       A string which is the value.

I have a json object like `{"time":1505900658464}` and when i use optstring i expect it to convert this long value to string ,but it actually returns " " (instead of converted long values as string).Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

First, the `optString()` method is supposed to return empty string: "" if there is no available String value.
See the [Documentation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#optString(java.lang.String))

Second, the object `{"time":1505900658464}` has long value not string. You should use `optLong` instead. See the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#optLong(java.lang.String)).

Also, you might need to read this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226288/json-jsonobject-optstring-returns-string-null), and for converting time from Unix (that's the format you provided in your example) to simpleDateFormat see [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432735/convert-unix-time-stamp-to-date-in-java)

Comment: then what does `If the value is not a string and is not null, then it is coverted to a string.` -means

Comment: it means if you are not sure that the key is always there or that its value is null or not a string..then it should give you empty string without crashing the app .